# Android Sqlite to .csv with CSVWriter - csv file not visible after creation

Tags: android, sqlite, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export my custom SQLite database into an Excel-readable format. I am using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724866/how-to-convert-data-base-records-into-csv-file-in-android) to convert my .db to a .csv. The code seems to work well, I get no exceptions thrown and the `CSVWriter` says that the file was exported successfully. I am exporting to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).` However, when I open the Downloads folder on the device, I don't see any .csv files.

I checked my code by writing a simple text file, and the text file shows up in the same directory, but not the .csv file. Also, my database is tested with System print, it is not empty - it is working and storing info properly.

Any clues? Am I missing something? My database is using `fts3`, could that affect this? Here's code that creates the .csv file before copying the database:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args)
     {
         File dbFile=getDatabasePath(patientData.DATABASE_NAME);

         File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
         File file = new File(path, "patients.csv");

         try
         {
             file.createNewFile();
             CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                 ...
             }
          ....
      }
```

Please let me know if any more info is needed from me!

Comment: Nevermind. A day later I opened up my android tablet again and the files magically appeared there. It must have been some bug that was not in my program. If anyone cares to know the above code is working.