# converting sqlite database to excel in android

Tags: android, excel, sqlite

I am trying to take the data from my database and create an excel csv file from this data. I have looked at some tutorials but am not sure how to go about this. any advice? I have made some progess but got lots of errors.

I'm not sure where to start but here's my dbadapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_WORKOUTDATE = "workoutDate";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES = "notes";

private static final String TAG = "WorkoutDBAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mdb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WorkoutDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "workouts";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists workouts " +
                "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "title VARCHAR not null, " +
                "workoutDate date, " +
                "notes VARCHAR );";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workouts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}


public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mdb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDBHelper != null) {
        mDBHelper.close();
    }
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String title, String workoutdate, String notes) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_WORKOUTDATE, workoutdate);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES, notes);

    return mdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}


//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords() {
    Cursor mCursor = mdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_WORKOUTDATE, KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
}
```

here is my exportData Class:I have lots of errors with the CSV

```
public class ExportData {
File dbFile = getDatabasePath("WorkoutDB.sqlite");
Databasehelper mDBHelper = new Databasehelper(getApplicationContext());
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
if (!exportDir.exists())
{
    exportDir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(exportDir, "csvname.csv");
try
{
    file.createNewFile();
    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName",null);
    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
    while(curCSV.moveToNext())
    {
        //Which column you want to exprort
        String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
    }
    csvWrite.close();
    curCSV.close();
}
catch(Exception sqlEx)
{
    Log.e("ExportData", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
}


}
```

Comment: Did you try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068774/sqlite-database-programmatically-convert-into-excel-file-format-in-android)

Comment: yeah i have tried that but don't fully understand

Comment: What was that problem with that lib?

Comment: @rekire sorry what do you mean?