# Convert String in JSON format into CSV / List of Strings

Tags: java, json, jsf, csv, jsf-2

I have created an CSV exporter where I am converting String in JSON format into the Collection of objects and then into the List of strings.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();   
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<itemModel>>(){}.getType();
Collection<itemModel> objects = gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
// jsonString = "[{"name":"A","number":25},{"name":"B","number":26}]"
String filename = "export.csv";
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
ec.responseReset();
ec.setResponseContentType("text/comma-separated-values");
ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (itemModel obj : objects) {
        strings.add(obj.getName() + ";" + obj.getNumber() +"\n");
    }
    for (String s : strings) {
        output.write(s.getBytes());
    }
fc.responseComplete();
```

Now, I would like to do the adding of a new string into the List dynamically and replace this row: `strings.add(obj.getName() + ";" + obj.getNumber() +"\n");` It should be more robust. Is somehow possible call all getters if I dont know exact names of properties?

Or is better solution how to convert String in JSON format into the List of strings?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724866/how-to-convert-data-base-records-into-csv-file-in-android. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for a recommendation but I don't see there a possible solution. I need to call all getters of object class dynamically.. or find another better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override toString() method in itemModel Class and build your string according to CSV foramt

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(name);
    builder.append(";");
    builder.append(number);
    builder.append("\n");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

// finally wrtie

```
 List<itemModel> itemModels = gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
         for (itemModel itemModel : itemModels) {
               output.write(itemModel.toString().getBytes());
        }
```

Comment: Absolutely wonderful! It would probably never figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing toString() of ItemModel is good if you already know all the properties.

You can use Reflection to get all the properties if you already don't know them.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! I was trying to implement Reflection but I didn't resolve how to call found getters inside loop `for (itemModel obj : objects) { }` But still toString() is sufficient for me.