# Sqlite pass information table txt file from android app

Tags: android

I would like to guide me about a small problem on android.
I need to get information from a table in my application and pass it to a text file or csv.

You can make a select *, create the file and pass that information?

Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this code help you :

```
private void exportDB() {

        File dbFile=getDatabasePath("MyDBName.db");
        DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
        if (!exportDir.exists())
        {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(exportDir, "csvname.csv");
        try
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts",null);
            csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            while(curCSV.moveToNext())
            {
                //Which column you want to exprort
                String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
            }
            csvWrite.close();
            curCSV.close();
        }
        catch(Exception sqlEx)
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
        }
```

[Exporting SQLite Database to csv file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367270/exporting-sqlite-database-to-csv-file-in-android)

[How to convert data base records into csv file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724866/how-to-convert-data-base-records-into-csv-file-in-android)

Comment: Sorry to be slow to respond, I had a lot of work after that problem, your code support me a lot, thank you very much.
regards

Comment: If this answer useful please vote up ;)