# Will emailing a .csv file work?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, csv

So I am fairly new to android programming. I have a database and I want to be able to take the information from the database stored on the android device, store it in a .csv file, attach it to an email, and send it to the receiver. This is however my first time working with a .csv file and I want to make sure I am doing it right.

I looked at this page: [Convert database .db file into .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665057/convert-database-db-file-into-csv)

But I am not sure the correct way to implement this using my current code, or even if this is what I am looking for.

I also tried using a bit of: [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

and noticed a section about dumping SQL into a .csv, would this be the best way to implement it? Any and all help and advice would be appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not too commited to attaching a csv file, it is really easy to just dump a big string into the body of an email, and send it to someone.  You don't have the issue of writing a local file and attaching it.

When sending an email you can just add:

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);

where emailBody is a big string that has your data in it.

At least this might be an interim solution?

Here is a little code that can send an email with a big string of text in it.

```
              String emailSubject = " Sent from my Android";
        String emailBody = "";


        // create a big String that has your data in it called emailBody

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");

                           // send it to yourself for testing
        // i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , new
        // String[]{"myemailaddress@fortesting.com"});

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(HistoryActivity.this,
                    "There are no email clients installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: That does not sound like a bad idea, but is it easy to turn a database into a big string for an email body? I currently have an database with 10 Columns and I don't just want the email to look like an ugly cluster. I would prefer it to look somewhat organized haha. Perhaps I should just go with a simple .txt file? Also I am using a modified code for email that I found at: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android . It should not make a difference from what I can tell, but if it does I would like you to be at least informed to help.

Comment: All of this depends... do you know the users of your app will have a gmail client on their devices?  I'm nervous about apps sending email without the user saying it's OK.  The code that uses Javax.mail looks pretty comprehensive.  I wonder if the apps on my phone sending a lot of email that I don't know about? 

Saving the content of the db into a file is not much different from saving it into a big String - iff you know that the db is quite small.  It will use up the RAM pretty quickly, so the general soln of dumnping into a file is better if you don't know that it is a small amount of data.

Comment: Yes, this app is mainly being tailor made for a small business I work at, the users will be a very small group of people, 5 to be exact. Everyone in the business has a domain email registered under gmail, so gmail should be no problem at all. As for the db, the workers are electrical and mechanical contractors, paid based on the number of hours worked at each job. Sometimes they work multiple jobs in one day. The db has a table with 10 necessary fields per job, and each job is one row. It seems that dumping into a file may be the better solution for this situation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have any good websites for source code for file streaming? I would love a good example to work with. I did a lot of streaming in C++ but I have not used it in a good while, and am still unfamiliar with most of android/JAVA (it is quite the beast haha). So examples for file streaming in android/JAVA would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Afraid I can't help there.  I'm not really an android expert but I agree it is a beast.  I try to take very small steps :)

Comment: Well thanks for all the help you have provided so far, it has been a big help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes CSVs can be emailed, however, CSVs can be hard to do anything with unless the end user knows how to open them in excel. (Or something similar).

It,will,just,look,like,this,:),

Is the receiver just going to be a member of the public?

Comment: Hi Jack and thanks for answering, I am doing this for a small private buisness I am working for over the summer. The goal is to take information from the android app, email it to someone for possible editing, then send it to another person to take the information and enter into a payroll program. I think potentially the end user simply needs to be able to comprehend the information so that they can open the file, look at it, and then enter into the payroll program. Does that help at all Jack?